# Parsing Custom Java MD5 to JS

Tags: javascript, java, md5

I'm trying to parse [this](https://github.com/fatbtc/fatbtc-api-rest/blob/master/master/java/fatbtc-api-rest-java/src/com/fatbtc/util/MD5Util.java) Java library into Javascript and I'm having a bit of trouble trying to understand it but my understanding of it is as follows.

Focusing on the MD5 aspects of createSign()

1. Creates a Treemap of ascending Alphabetical order
2. Initializes StringBuffer, a Set, and an Iterator.
3. for Each entry in the map it gets the key value and the object value and concatenates in a fashion similar to: " api=123&signType=MD5& "
4. Append "apiSecret="+secretKey to the end
5. getMDString() which just converts it to a string again a function I dont believe is necessary for JS

What I am having a hard time understanding is why when I place my elements in the order indicated in step 3, and append "apiSecret="+secretKey in step four I'm still getting invalid sign?